# How to remove hyperlink from meta_key wordpress

Tags: wordpress, function, hyperlink, href, meta-key

I have 11458 post in blog and i want to remove all link from value on `meta_key`.

example:

I have this on meta_key movies.

```
<ul>
<li><a href="http://mydomin/17541/">big art</a> (1954)</li>
<li><a href="http://mydomin/14368/">power</a> (1953)</li>

<li><img src="http://mydomin/wp-content/upload/56498654.jpg"/>
<a href="http://mydomin/14902/">down</a> (1953)</li>

<li><a href="http://mydomin/14847/">sorry man</a> (1950)</li>

<li><img src="http://mydomin/wp-content/upload/56456654.jpg"/>
<a href="http://mydomin/14902/">im wild</a> (1951)</li>
</ul>
```

i want change to this and save ( auto update post)

```
<ul>
<li>big art (1954)</li>
<li>power (1953)</li>
<li>down (1953)</li>
<li>sorry man (1950)</li>
<li>im wild (1951)</li>
</ul>
```

How can do that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your $meta_key and it will filter the result the way you want.

```
 $anchor_image_tag_remove_ar = array ('/<img[^>]+./','/<a[^<>]*?[^<>]*?>(.*?)<\/a>/');
 $new_html = preg_replace($anchor_image_tag_remove_ar, '$1', $meta_key);
```

You can also remove the anchor and image tag separately.

For Removing Image Tag

```
 preg_replace("/<img[^>]+\>/i", "(image) ", $meta_key);
```

For Removing Anchor Tag

```
 preg_replace('#<a.*?>([^>]*)</a>#i', '$1', $meta_key);
```

Comment: tnx for answer, What is the complete code for the meta_key movie? Where to copy this code ? sorry but this i am a Amateur